# How to prevent frost forming and growing over glass surface under cryogenic conditions?

Tags: experimental-physics

I am planning to do some experiments under cryogenic condition with vessels such as test tubes, beakers. Since I wish to observe what's happenning within the vessels directly， the existence of frost or fog will be of much trouble for me. Is there any good ways of preventing such stuff happening?

Comment: Keep the moisture in the room in minimum. Use filters on peoples faces so they don't contribute to the moisture in air of the facilities.

Comment: I do not give it as an answer, bcause I cannot try it, but I would experiment  with one of the hydrophobic sprays, as this http://technologylicensing.research.ufl.edu/technologies/14942_superhydrophobic-superoleophobic-spray-coating-that-makes-surfaces-self-cleaning .It might work . It has been tried?  see this http://www.academia.edu/27274839/Delayed_Frost_Growth_on_Jumping-Drop_Superhydrophobic_Surfaces  (have not read it because it needed signing up)

Answer (score 0):

The only good way is to put your kit in a vaccum. If this is a problem then you can put it in an airtight container and attempt to dry the air using silica gel or some similar dessicant, but getting the air completely dry is surprisingly hard. I speak from (bitter) experience.